# ploting a cosine wave using NASM x86 assembly

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm, x86-64, trigonometry

I have to plot a simple cosine(x) wave using assembly language. I have completed all the steps of the project as per my professor's instructions but I cannot get the program to print properly. This is the output I get,

```
linux2[14]% cat plot4.out
*****************************************
```

But it should be...

```
                  *****                  
                 *     *                 
                *       *                
               *         *               
              *           *              
             *             *             

            *               *            
           *                 *           

          *                   *          

         *                     *         
        *                       *        

       *                         *       
      *                           *      
     *                             *     
    *                               *    
  **                                 **  
**                                     **
```

Here is my code. Any assistance would be appreciated.

```
      SECTION .data         ; Data section, initialized variables
nrow:           dq 21       ; 21 rows
ncol:           dq 41       ; 41 columns
fmtc:           db "%c", 0  ; print one character at a time
fmtend:         db 10, 0    ; end a line
star:           db '*'      ; one character '*'
fmtendLen:  equ $-fmtend
pStar:      db  "*"
starLen:    equ $-pStar
pSpace:     db  " "
spaceLen:   equ $-pSpace
len:            equ $-star
spc:            db ' '
af:         dq 1.0, 0.0, -0.5 ; coefficients of polynomial, a_0 first
            dq 0.0, 0.041667, 0.0, -0.001389, 0.0, 0.000025
XF:         dq 0.0      ; computed
Y:          dq 0.0      ; computed
N:          dq 8        ; power of polynomial
X0:         dq -3.14159     ; start XF
DX0:            dq 0.15708      ; increment for XF  ncol-1  times
one:            dq 1.0
ten:            dq 10.0
none:           dq -1.0
nten:           dq -10.0
twenty:         dq 20.0
zero:           dq 0.0
newline:    db 10

    section .bss

a2: resb    21*41       ; two dimensional array of bytes
i:  resq    1       ; row subscript
j:  resq    1       ; col subscript
k:  resq    1

    SECTION .text   ; Code section.

    global _start   ; the standard gcc entry point
_start:                     ; the program label for the entry point


;;;   clear a2 to space
    mov     rax,0           ; i=0
    mov     [i],rax

loopi:
    mov     rax,[i]
    mov     rbx,0       ; j=0
    mov     [j],rbx
loopj:
    mov     rax,[i]
    mov     rbx,[j]
    imul    rax,[ncol]  ; i*ncol
    add     rax, rbx    ; i*ncol + j
    mov     dl, [spc]   ; need just character, byte
    mov     [a2+rax],dl ; store space

    mov     rbx,[j]
    inc     rbx         ; j++
    mov     [j],rbx
    cmp     rbx,[ncol]  ; j<ncol
    jne     loopj

    mov     rax,[i]
    inc     rax         ; i++
    mov     [i],rax
    cmp     rax,[nrow]      ; i<ncol
    jne     loopi

;;;   end clear a2 to space

    mov     rax, 0          ;i = 0
    mov     [i], rax
    mov     rbx, 0          ;j = 0
    mov     [j], rbx

cos:
    mov     rcx,[N]         ; loop iteration count initialization, n
    fld     qword [af+8*rcx] ; accumulate value here, get coefficient a_
h5loop:
    fmul    qword [XF]  ; * XF
    fadd    qword [af+8*rcx-8] ; + aa_n-i
    loop    h5loop         ; decrement rcx, jump on non zero
    fstp    qword [Y]          ; store Y


;;; ; ;  compute k
    fld qword [Y]
    fadd qword [one]
    fmul qword [ten]
    fmul qword [none]
    fadd qword [twenty]
    fistp qword [k]

;;; ; ; ; ; rax gets k * ncol + j
    mov     rax, [k]
    mov     rbx, [j]
    imul    rax, [ncol]
    add     rax, rbx

;;; ; ; put "*" in dl, then dl into [a2+rax]
    mov     dl, [star]
    mov     [a2+rax], dl

;;; ; ; XF = XF + DX0
    fld     qword [XF]
    fadd    qword [DX0]
    fistp   qword [XF]


    mov     rbx, [j]
    inc     rbx         ; j++

    mov     [j], rbx
    cmp     rbx,[ncol]  ; j<ncol
    jne     cos

;;;   print
    mov     rax,0       ; i=0
    mov     [i],rax

ploopi:
    mov     rax,[i]
    mov     rbx,0       ; j=0
    mov     [j],rbx

ploopj:

    mov rax,[i]
    mov rbx,[j]
    mov dl, [spc]

    imul    rax,[ncol]
    add     rax, rbx


    mov     rax, [i]        ; a2+i*ncol+j  is byte
    imul    rax, [ncol]
    add     rax, [j]
    add     rax, a2
    mov     rsi, rax ; address of character to print
    mov     rax, 1       ; system call 1 is write
    mov     rdi, 1       ; file handle 1 is stdout
    mov rdx, 1       ; number of bytes
    syscall          ; invoke operating system to do the write

;;;  print here

    mov     rbx,[j]
    inc     rbx         ; j++
    mov     [j],rbx
    cmp     rbx,[ncol]  ; j<ncol
    jne     ploopj

    mov     rdi, fmtend
    mov     rax, 1
    mov     rdi, 1  ; file handle 1 is stdout
    mov     rsi, newline ; address of string to output
    mov     rdx, 1       ; number of bytes
    syscall

;;;  print here

    mov     rax,[i]
    inc     rax         ; i++
    mov     [i],rax
    cmp     rax,[nrow]      ; i<ncol
    jne     ploopi

;;;   print a2

    mov     eax, 60 ; system call 60 is exit
    xor     rdi, rdi    ; exit code 0
    syscall             ; invoke operating system to exit
```

Comment: Use a debugger to single step your program and see where it goes wrong.

Comment: This might be really stupid...but could you tell me how to do that?

Comment: If you are not familiar with a debugger, it might be easiest to grab something with a GUI, such as `ddd`. Then load your program and click the buttons. I trust you can find it out yourself, can't teach you how to use a debugger in a comment here.

Comment: At the end of http://stackoverflow.com/tags/x86/info is short entry with "go to" links for the most common debugger in GNU world `gdb`. (`ddd` is built upon it, extending it's text UI .. there are few other debuggers in linux available, but it requires some searching and setting up (sometimes even compiling from source))

Comment: I figured out the debugger and I stepped through the debugger but can't make sense of it. Only thing that I noticed is that it never reaches the last line the steps kept repeating could this mean that the program is stuck in a loop?

Comment: steps 51 -62 keep repeating

Comment: You do have a couple of loops in there, so those repeating are kinda by design. No idea which lines are 51-62, but if it's an endless loop you might have messed up the exit condition so look at that.

Comment: its loopj: label up until the first jne statement...that loops endlessly...is that normal?

Comment: It shouldn't loop endlessly, only 41 times per single "i" (in total 21*41 times). Wow, you wrote that source, right? Check with debugger memory content of [i] and [j] to see how the loop is progressing. Also you may want to fill `a2` array with bogus values to see how it is cleared... also you may want to clear that memory by simpler way....

Comment: @Ped7g no not all of the source. loopi and loopj are provided by the instructor which is why I can't really make sense of it. Thank you though I will try to figure out what it going on...

Comment: Are you serious? I was not going to comment on quality of that code, because I assumed it was produced by student (then it's OK). If this is code from your instructor, then I'm deeply confused... my first instinct is yelling "run away while you can". But maybe he did that on purpose... I just can't figure out what that purpose may be. Torture of people on SO, who will see the source? Maybe.

Comment: @Ped7g yeah it definitely is torture. I just don't understand how the program can print something out but the debugger says its stuck in a loop that doesn't invoke any printing...

Comment: As Ped7g said, it's not stuck, it's just looping 21*41 times. If you put a breakpoint on line 63 (after the `jne`) you can let the program run and it will eventually stop there. It would also help to know which part is actually written by you, as the error is likely in there. You should also comment the code to show what it is trying to do.

Comment: Yeah, put breakpoint after those loops to run through them fast... but you should first learn how to watch memory, so you can verify the `[i]` and `[j]` is really progressing... You will need this skill while debugging that other part of code.

Comment: BTW, I meant torture of seasoned assembly programmers. Actually that code is written in a "simple way" for newbies, so if you will read through it and focus what values are changed and how, it should give you lot more sense, than my short variant, which may look a bit "obfuscated" for somebody learning assembly. So I don't think the "torture" applies for you, not earned it yet. Try harder, after you will be able to simplify your instructor code on your own, then we may talk about "torture".

Comment: @Ped7g do you think it makes more sense to just start over then? Like a lot has been said but I still don't know what is wrong with my code...

Comment: First fix is: change `fistp qword [XF]` to `fstp     qword [XF]`. But if you don't understand why, then yes, you should start over.. I mean the whole Assembly course, not with this code, this code is quite advanced for somebody who doesn't understand difference between `fistp` and `fstp` and why that breaks your code. If you will fix that `[XF]` update, it will start to crash, because you try to draw `'*'` somewhere at [21,-1] coordinate, writing into protected memory.

Comment: If you understand what you are doing, you can certainly write code sanitizing `[k]` to be within valid range `0..21` only. So "clamp" it to valid range. Then you can play with coefficients of formula to get graph which will look as you wish... that's pure math stuff, not programming related.

Comment: we are told that k=(20.0 - (y+1.0)*(10.)

Comment: I made the changes that you mentioned and the program no longer seg faults it just prints all the stars like before but at the bottom of the grid instead of at the top

Comment: I added output of my fixed version.. so you went wrong with your fix somewhere. Now use the debugger + watch the values in memory, to verify the values like `[XF]` and `[k]` are as expected. I did change 1 line (XF) and added 3 more (eax = 0 when invalid [k]) ... plus few more lines for dots/#, but those are not important for you. So the code in your question is *almost* working.

Comment: I took another look at the *k* calculation. I think it's correct, as you wrote k = (y+1.0)*10.0*(-1.0)+20.0 in the code. So I think the source *y* is not in -1.0 .. +1.0 range, ie. your polynomial approximation of `cos x` is probably wrong (wrong coefficients or order of them? I'm too tired to dig into those). Anyway that should be easy to check in debugger, what kind of source *y* values are coming into *k* calculation.

Comment: corrections I made are the following fld   qword [X0] and fstp  qword [XF]  initialize XF before  cos: fistp qword [k]   ;  not fstp and fstp  qword [XF]  ;  not fistp

Comment: deleting the code from your question invalidates the answer (and turns it into a non-question with no [mcve]).  Don't do that.  If Ped7g's answer solved your problems, you should mark it as accepted (checkbox under the vote arrows)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code doesn't work as expected because `[XF]` update is wrong:

```
fistp   qword [XF]  ; will store integer.
```

After you will fix XF, it will crash, because calculated y value gets outside of [0,0] -> [41,21] coordinates.

You can make your code more robust by adding min/max coordinates clamping before drawing stars, so in case your calculation produces wrong [x,y], it will not write star into some memory, but something else (I put there `'#'` at y=0 to see where your graph goes wrong).

After that you will probably want to fix the graph... that's up to you.

Anyway, I have some more comments to your Assembly technique (or as I noted from comments, technique of your instructor). I can tolerate that as student's work, but only so.

To become computer programmer you shouldn't just translate every stupidity literally into computer commands. If people would program like that, sorting would be still full O(n^2) in every case, and nobody would ever create any compression algorithm. You should fundamentally understand what kind of calculation you want to achieve, and try to simplify where possible.

Let me give you example from your code. The initial part is putting space character to every position of a2 array. So essentially it is doing:

```
for (i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
  for (j = 0; j < 41; ++j)
    a2[i * ncol + j] = ' ';
```

There's minor problem I have with it.. it's done literally. Like every f*cking sign in every expression, and everything is loaded/stored into memory back and forth, like registers on CPU didn't exist.

But it's even worse, I have also major problem with it. If you put your programmer hat on, and think what calculation is going on in that part, you should figure out the final state of that calculation is, that whole memory allocated for `a2` is filled with value `32` (`' '`). And the a2 occupies consecutive 21*41 bytes in memory.

So to do the same thing you may write this code:

```
lea rdi,[a2]    ; address of first byte of a2
lea ecx,[i-a2]  ; rcx = size of a2 array in bytes
; (using label "i" after it) And only ecx as 21*41 < 2^32
mov al,' '      ; space value directly (why [spc]?)
rep stosb       ; fill rcx bytes at rdi with al
```

It will fill whole `a2` with spaces. If those loops would go by columns, than this code would fill it differently, by rows. But if you are interested only into the result of the calculation (whole array set to `' '`), than you don't care if it was done by rows, columns or circles.

etc, etc... there are some more weird things in that code, but I'm not willing to rewrite it whole to my taste, I hope this is enough to illustrate what I had on my mind.

---

BTW, I would not expect a student to end immediately with `rep stosb` variant (and even that can be further optimized for performance by padding `a2` to be of 16 or 32 multiply size, and fill it up with some SSE instructions or at least `stosd`).

But at least recognizing the inner loop is doing `i * ncol + j` in every iteration... while you may do:

```
for (i = 0; i < 21; ++i) {
  rowindex = i*ncol + 0;
  for (j = 0; j < 41; ++j) {
    a2[rowindex] = ' ';
    ++rowindex;
  }
}
```

... that's like bare minimum. Then if you would debug that, you would notice that `rowindex = i*ncol + 0;` is equal to the already set value from previous line end, so you need to do only `rowindex = 0;` ahead of both `for` loops:

```
charindex = 0;
for (i = 0; i < 21; ++i)
  for (j = 0; j < 41; ++j)
    a2[charindex++] = ' ';
```

And now you should already see the two `for` loops can be replaced by single `for (count = 0; count < 21*41; ++count)` ... but wait a second, isn't that equal to `charindex`? Oh yeah, it is.

```
for (i = 0; i < 21*41; ++i) a2[i] = ' ';
```

And that's equivalent of my `rep stosb`, but if you would write that with simple `mov/inc/dec/jnz` instructions as loop (because you don't know the `rep stosb`), I would be perfectly fine with it (it would be executed in roughly same time).

But doing 21*41 `imul` instructions is like... blasphemy. There was time, when doing 800 multiplications of 32 bit numbers would take about 3-5 seconds. Now somebody is using that computing power to clear consecutive array of bytes. Pain...

---

BTW, this is the output of your original code (after fixing `[XF]` update, and clamping values... and I replaced spaces with dots, and clamped Y values turn `*` into `#`.

```
.......................*#################
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
.........................................
*.....................*..................
.*.......................................
..*......................................
.........................................
...*.................*...................
.........................................
....*....................................
.....*..............*....................
.........................................
......*............*.....................
.......*.................................
........*.........*......................
.........*.......*.......................
..........*..............................
...........*...**........................
............***..........................
```

Comment: @MohammadMarzooghian If this is assembly school course, I bet you did start with more simple things.. go back through them several times. If you started immediately with this, then either find some tutorials on your own, or ask your teacher for better introduction. While going through simpler tutorials: you must not learn instructions by memorizing certain patterns, like lyrics of song. That will get you nowhere. You need to understand the math in the CPU+memory, how the bit values are changing with each instruction. And how that maps to original algorithm and builds the output of program.

Comment: fld   qword [X0]
   fstp  qword [XF]  ; need to initialize XF before  cos:

   fistp qword [k]   ;  not fstp

   fstp  qword [XF]  ;  not fistp

Comment: That was the fix needed

Comment: Thank you for your help!